# Lenovo S740 (i7-9750H) Extremely Poor Battery Life on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: nvidia, power-management, lenovo, battery, nvidia-prime

I need some urgent assistance with my new Lenovo S740 and battery life on Ubuntu 19.10. I purchased this laptop for development work but the battery life has been so abysmal that I am considering just going back to my old Lenovo T450 while I can still bail out and return this laptop.

My S740’s loadout:

- 15” 4k display
- i7-9750H
- Nvidia 1650 GPU
- 16 GB RAM
- half-terabyte NVME drive

Lenovo advertises the S740 as having “all day battery life” defined as “up to 10 hours” on the 4k display. I’m getting closer to 3 hours and I would consider my usage fairly typical/light. A few tabs open in Chrome (no videos), Atom editor open, and maybe a terminal open. That’s it. Backlight is not bright, I keep it dimmed just to get that 3.5 hours out of a full charge.

It should be noted that when I boot into **Windows I get much better battery life- on par with the advertised hours. So this is Ubuntu-specific.**

Things I have tried so far:

```
• This laptop has a dGPU so I thought maybe that was staying awake and chewing up my battery life. I set the PRIME profile to Intel and rebooted. I have also confirmed that only the iGPU is in use both in the *About/Details* section of Ubuntu and with `lspci`
• Disabled bluetooth
• Checked for BIOS updates; currently on newest
• `tlp` on in battery mode
• `powertop –autotune`
    ◦ Neither `tlp` nor `powertop –autotune` made any noticeable difference
• Ran `powertop` which only shows what I already know- high power consumption due primarily due to the CPU and display
```

Doing a back of the envelope calculation, I believe `powertop` is accurate. My battery has a 69 Wh capacity nominally. At a power consumption of 16 Watts, this would put me right at 4.3 hours, which is close to my realized battery life.

Attached is a screenshot from `powertop` :

[image: powertop]

Any ideas? Are i7-9750H/Coffee Lake CPUs just not supported on Linux/Ubuntu yet?

Comment: battery consumption is accurate, the real battery life is less than 4.3h due to safety margin (don't use all energy store inside a battery, it won't be able to charged after, best way to destroy it)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's not really my question. My question is: why is my battery life so poor compared to Windows? Is it just because of the kernel? Any other ideas for how I can fix this? Ubuntu is my favorite OS since it's just far more convenient for me to stay within Linux when I work, so I don't really relish the idea of going back to Windows.